# How to modify a value in a class? (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm simply trying to add or subtract from a value in a class, from a main file, but it seems to always reset this value **zero**. Being a beginner I don't really understand why?! Everytime I print player.worldPositionY it says either *-1*, *1*, or *0* (if neither 1 or 2 was selected - moveForward or moveBack)

I have two simple files, Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

int keyboardInput;

int main()
{
    Player player;

    cin.get();
    cin >> keyboardInput;

    if (keyboardInput == 1){
        player.moveForward();
    } else if (keyboardInput == 2){
        player.moveBack();
    }

    cout << "Y: " << player.worldPositionY << endl;
    main();
}
```

And a player.h:

```
class Player {
public:
    int worldPositionY = 0;

    void moveForward();
    void moveBack();
};

void Player::moveForward(){worldPositionY += 1;}

void Player::moveBack(){worldPositionY -= 1;}
```

I'm clearly missing something. Please help!

Comment: Using `main` in your program is not allowed.

Comment: More to the point, *calling* `main()` in your program is not allowed =P

Comment: Also, making all the members `public` just defies OOP.

Comment: @WhosCaig Calling `main()` is certainly allowed. Though the ISO C++ committee doesn't have an opinion about what the behavior should be, your compiler might support it (in which case, there really is only one obvious way to do so). I suspect that a diagnostic may also be required from a conforming C++ implementation, if a call to `main` occurs in a C++ translation unit, but that's no impediment against making it work.  C++ doesn't disallow anything, it only makes requirements about what shall work (and how), and what is to be diagnosed.

Comment: @Kaz, It seems pretty clear to me. *The function main shall not be used within a program.*

Comment: @chris That just means "the function `main` shall not be used, *if* the behavior is to be well-defined by ISO C++, and free of the requirement for a diagnostic out of a conforming implementation". That doesn't quite equate to "not allowed".

Comment: @Kaz, Apparently I need to get cracking on that terminology then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `main` recursively. You don't want to do this, do this instead:

```
int main()
{
    Player player;

    while (true)
    {
        cin.get();
        cin >> keyboardInput;

        if (keyboardInput == 1){
            player.moveForward();
        } else if (keyboardInput == 2){
            player.moveBack();
        }

        cout << "Y: " << player.worldPositionY << endl;
    }
}
```

Calling `main` recursively means that your `player` object is recreated every time you input a value, which is why your values were always either `-1` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for explaining, works like a dream. I'm a beginner in C++ so a lot of things still don't make sense but I'm learning every day :) Thanks again both you and Arun A.S. For all the useful information!

Comment: Not a problem at all. Welcome to Stack Overflow as well. Remember to mark the best answers as being the "accepted answer", your answeree will thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you call `main()`, the object is created again with default value zero. Now, you can do as @cmbasnett stated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860812/4516316), or you can make `worldPositionY` `static` like

```
class Player {
public:
    static int worldPositionY;   // making it static 

    void moveForward();
    void moveBack();
};
int Player::worldPositionY=0;  // don't forget to initialize it outside as well.
```